# Windows Sandbox Mapped Folder Not Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-sandbox

I made a sandbox configuration file with a mapped folder and some other settings, but when I open sandbox (by double clicking the config file), my mapped folder doesn't show up on the desktop of the VM.
This is my config file:

```
<Configuration> 
<Networking>Enable</Networking>
<VGpu>Enable</VGpu>
<MappedFolders>
    <MappedFolder>
        <HostFolder>H:\Sandbox-Files\</HostFolder>
        <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
    </MappedFolder>
</MappedFolders>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Two things.   (1) Sandbox lives on a NAT network for some isolation, so take that into account.  (2) Sandbox disappears (so does your network) when you close it.

Comment: I know sandbox removed everthing after I close it but this file is on my normal computer, if i doubleclick that it opens sandbox with that config (at least it should). As far as I know when I open sandbox with that config file I should see a folder on my desktop called "Sandbox-Files" because I added that to the config, but this isn't working

Comment: In all the examples I have seen, there was no anti-slash at the end of the HostFolder tag.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out I had to also add a line in the config file to specify where the folder would be located in the VM.

```
<Configuration>
    <Networking>Enable</Networking>
    <vGPU>Enable</vGPU>
    <MappedFolders>
        <MappedFolder>
            <HostFolder>C:\Users\flgc\Documents\projects\@planner\@work\planner_django_old_db\planner\build_production</HostFolder>
            <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
            <SandboxFolder>C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Sandbox-Files\</SandboxFolder>
        </MappedFolder>
    </MappedFolders>
</Configuration>
```

I had to add the SandboxFolder tag for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not HAVE TO add the  tag unless you do not want it on your desktop. If it works with it then that's great for you, but from my experience Sandbox prefers your location to not have the `/` after the folder at the end. My 1st one ran where maybe 1 in 5 times the mapped folder wouldn't be there & I'd just close & restart. Then I removed the trailing / & it always showed up. I wanna say it was fine at 1st but maybe an update made it stop working all the time, but that was awhile ago so I cannot say for sure